# Webkit: drag and drop block elements (div, span) in a contenteditable container

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, webkit

Does somebody know how to drag and drop the whole content of a div/span inside a `contenteditable` container in Chrome?

I have something like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
 <p>Some text</p>
 <span class="image_frame" contenteditable="false" //don't want to edit its content>
  <img src="/test.jpg" style="position:relative;z-index=-1;//hack to not copy the image">
 </span>
</div>
```

I would like to move the span element with the image between "Some" and "text". This does work in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the html5 `draggable = "true"` attribute to the span element.
Tested it on chrome (Version 23.0.1271.64 m) and its dropping the image between "some" and "text" ..
Hope this helps.